# Write a macro with \command, {, and } in argument

Tags: macros

I understand that TeX macro arguments can be parsed using proper delimiters. And as the classic example goes in The TeXbook,

[image]

Along the same line, I tried to define a macro (for some special purpose, the following is actually a much simpler scenario of my situation),

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\mycommand\cone\bgroup#1\egroup\ctwo #2.#3\end{#1:#2:#3}

\begin{document}

\mycommand\cone{One}\ctwo Two.Three\end

\end{document}
```

Where, `\cone` and `\ctwo` are used/system defined macros, and I am not interested in these definitions, rather I would like to ignore them. My points of interest are the three arguments.

Now, when I try compile the above file, I get the error message,

```
! Use of \mycommand doesn't match its definition.
l.10 \mycommand\cone{
                     One}\ctwo Two.Three
```

This is where I get stuck.

Please note that the "`\cone{One}\ctwo Two.Three`" part is rather unalterable. So, any suggested change will have to be in the definition of 
`\mycommand`.

I know that as has been pointed out also in The TeXbook, the parameter list can not contain any braces. To circumvent this, I tried using `\bgroup` and `\egroup`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\def\mycommand\cone\bgroup#1\egroup\ctwo #2.#3\end{#1:#2:#3}
```

would require explict `\bgroup`. It seems like you want

```
\def\mycommand\cone#1\ctwo #2.#3\end{#1:#2:#3}
```

Then

```
\mycommand\cone{One}\ctwo Two.Three\end
```

or

```
 \mycommand\cone One\ctwo Two.Three\end
```

would have `#1` = `One`

Comment: Indeed TeX strips off a pair of braces around a delimited argument if this doesn't lead to unbalanced braces (double dangerous bend at the end of page 203 that ends on the following page of the TeXbook).